# De-serializing a graph generates an exception in Java

Tags: java, object, exception, arraylist, serialization

I created a graph consisting of nodes and edges as seen here:

```
public class Edge implements Serializable {
    private final Node neighbor;
    private final double weight;

    public Edge(Node neighbor, double weight) {
        this.neighbor = neighbor;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Node getNeighbor() {
        return neighbor;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}

public class Node implements Serializable {
    private final String name;
    private final ArrayList<Edge> edges;

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.edges = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> getEdges() {
        return edges;
    }

    public void addEdge(Edge edge) {
        this.edges.add(edge);
    }
}

public class Graph implements Serializable {
    private final ArrayList<Node> nodes;

    public Graph() {
        nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Graph(ArrayList<Node> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }

    public ArrayList<Node> getNodes() {
        return new ArrayList<>(nodes);
    }
}
```

I am attempting to serialize and de-serialize the Graph with like this:

```
    public Graph deSerialize() {
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        try {
            FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(aFile);
            ObjectInputStream oIS = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
            graph = (Graph) oIS.readObject();
            oIS.close();
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return graph;
    }

    private void serialize(Graph graph) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(aFile);
            ObjectOutputStream oOS = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
            oOS.writeObject(graph);
            oOS.close();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The serialization works fine (as far as I know) but during the de-serialization the following StackTrace is printed and I can't figure out what is causing it:
[UPDATED]: (happens when serializing)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:339)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:897)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

[ADDED]: (happens when de-serializing)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:3169)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1847)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2464)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2358)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2196)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1679)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:493)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:451)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:929)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

I have tried a few different things including serializing the ArrayList of nodes themselves among others but I cannot get to the bottom of it.
Can someone please help me fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Could you add your `catch` statements please?  `oOS.close();` is in a place it won't be called if the serialization did in fact throw an error.

Comment: And that is _precisely_ why you should use the try-with-resources, which was developed specifically for cases like this.

Comment: I do have them, I just didn't add them in here. Apologies...How can I edit this question? I'm new to StackOverflow!
Done. Thanks for the help!

Comment: At the very end of your post, to the left of your name, there's a series of links "Share Edit Follow" etc.  It's Edit.

Comment: OK, and I'll assume you don't see a stack trace during serialization.  We could use a driver program that demonstrates the error.  Like a `main` program that adds two nodes to a graph, then serializes and deserializes, and throws an error on your system.

Comment: Hmm... I got a little confused earlier but I do see a stack trace when serializing and deserializing apparently. I'll try to add small graph, serialize and de-serialize it. I'll report what happens.

Comment: So, it does work in main if I manually add a Node, give it some Edges then add it to an ArrayList which then goes into a Graph. I serialized the graph with the same code, de-serialized it and output the node's name and edges' names. It all works properly...

Comment: To add on to my last comment, it does not work with the same graph in main either, only a graph that contains three nodes I temporarily created.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

"It does that."

Perhaps that's not very helpful.

When you serialise `Node`, `Edge`s will be recursive seralised. An `Edge` contains a `Node` so that will get serialised recursively. For even a modest graph that can lead to a fair recursion depth, and each level of recursion uses up a sizable block of stack space.

A linked list is the canonical example of this going wrong. The standard technique is to use a custom serial form for the whole graph. For example, whenever you come across an `Edge` you could give it a sequence number (keeping track in a `Map<Edge,Node>`. Serialise the `Node`s with `edges` `transient` followed by an array of `Edge` ids. Follow this with the `Edge` objects in order. When deserialising, add the `Edge`s back to the `Node`s.